# function access variable in module.exports file in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to find the best way to access function variables that are being used as parameters in other functions in another module. The `parsefile.js` is a Node.js script that is exported as package module and two functions. `getfirst` and `getsecond` need to access the variables that are passed from index.js like `'a', 'b'` from  `parsefile('a', 'b', 'c')`. Other than using `global`, do we have another way to do it?

```
// index.js from some application
const parsefile = require('./parsefile')
parsefile('a', 'b', 'c')


//parsefile.js exports about package module
function getfirst() {
  if (global.f && global.s) {
    return `i have totally 2 arguments: ${global.f}///${global.s}`
  }
  return `first arguments is ${global.f}`
}

function getsecond() {
  return `second arguments is ${global.s}`
}

module.exports = (...args) => {
  global.f = args[0];
  global.s = args[1];
  Promise.all([getfirst(), getsecond()]).then(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(`return from getfirst: ${first}`);
    console.log(`return from getsecond: ${second}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with TypeScript?

Comment: Additionally, is this code your own? Or is this just an example? We only review code that is actually intended to be used, not dummy code written for expressing an idea. Finally, I suggest you read up variables.

Comment: Yes it's my code.

Comment: On a broad level, what does the code achieve? How are the functions returned by parsefile used in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Since `getfirst()` and `getsecond()` are called only within `parsefile.js`, you can just define an object inside this file (something like this `const local = {}` at the top of your file) and use it instead of `global`.